# Creating disabled state for my PNG image button

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm working on toolbar control and need to come up with some kind of effect to make button greyed out or something.

So, let's say I got PNG icons and I want to "discolor" them somehow. Can this be achieved with XAML? Or do I need to write code for this? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use per-pixel filters, as Christian Graus demonstrates in his [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 1 - Per Pixel Filters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx) ([Download source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11/CSharpFiltersProject.zip)):

```
unsafe
{
    byte * p = (byte *)(void *)Scan0;

    int nOffset = stride - b.Width*3;

    byte red, green, blue;

    for(int y=0;y < b.Height;++y)
    {
        for(int x=0; x < b.Width; ++x )
        {
           blue = p[0];
           green = p[1];
           red = p[2];

           p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = (byte)(.299 * red 
               + .587 * green 
               + .114 * blue);

           p += 3;
       }
       p += nOffset;
   }
}
```

See the linked page for more examples and other filters.

Comment: Whoops! I didn't see that tag! However, after poking around on the net, I can't find anywhere that definitively says you _can't_ use them together.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Opacity of your image to 30 or 50 percent when Button.IsEnabled is false.

edit: I suppose you could change the Image.Source property to a disabled image file. There are a few ways to do this: have two image elements and bind the visibility property to the button's IsEnabled property; run the Image.Source property through a value converter; or use a Blend trigger to change the Source property when the IsEnabled property changes.

Comment: Color still going to be there and I don't want that

Comment: Then you need to use XAML resources instead of PNGs. This is one of several reasons that XAML resources are better than static image files.

Comment: My designer does not know how to work XAML. There is no way to alter images in SL?

Comment: You might be able to do something to the pixels (like get the Image in code behind, convert it to a WriteableBitmap, filter the WriteableBitmap.Pixels array down to greyscale, and then swap that image in for the original), but it's quite a bit of work.  A less CPU intensive approach (and one with less code thus less potential for error) is the approach I described in my edit where you have a regular PNG and a disable PNG for each button and then swap them out appropriately.

Comment: I thought about this first but didn't wan't all 50+ files on top. In my mind it is more maintenance-intensive approach to keep 2 copies.

Comment: It is more maintenance intensive, but your application will be more responsive than if you're swapping out WritableBitmap objects all the time.  Take the maintenance hit for the improved runtime experience.

Comment: Well. I have lot's of icons but maybe 10 will be displayed at the same time max. And most of them won't be disabled, so in my useage pattern I don't think performance will be of an issue.